# desktop does not appear but shortcut keys still open GUI applications

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am using Kubuntu 17.04.

Recently, when I log in to my session, the desktop won't appear, but all the services & programs are running. A cursor and a black screen is all I see at first, but I can open konsole and dolphin with shortcut keys.

Please let me know what information is needed to find the cause and fix the problem.

Comment: Did you change video card driver? This seems to me to be a not working video card driver. Reset it to begin with.